# Firefox issue rendering rotated image with perspective

Tags: html, css, firefox, perspective

I've created a cube in css with `perspevtive` and `rotateX/Y/X` and with some `translate` I put the screen/camera into this cube (the goal is to create a skybox).

While it's ok in Chrome, Firefox seems to have some problem displaying background-image on some faces when thoses faces are to inclined.

Here is a codepen for example : http://codepen.io/poolboy/full/MaNgVK/

Html

```
<section class="cube-container">
  <div id="cube">
    <figure class="front"></figure>
    <figure class="back"></figure>
    <figure class="right"></figure>
    <figure class="left"></figure>
    <figure class="top"></figure>
    <figure class="bottom"></figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Css

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cube-container {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 1024px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* animation: anim  20s linear infinite; */
}

#cube figure {
  margin: 0;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 1024px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /* border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cube .front  { background: url(http://www.poolboy.fr/images/front.jpg) ; transform: translateZ( 511px
) rotateY(   180deg ); }
#cube .back   { background: url(http://www.poolboy.fr/images/back.jpg) ; transform:  rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 511px ) rotateZ(180deg) rotateY(   180deg ); }
#cube .right  { background: url(http://www.poolboy.fr/images/right.jpg) ; transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 511px ) rotateY(   180deg ); }
#cube .left   { background: url(http://www.poolboy.fr/images/left.jpg) ; transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 511px ) rotateY(   180deg ); }
#cube .top    { background: url(http://www.poolboy.fr/images/top.jpg) ; transform: rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 511px ) rotateY(   180deg ); }
#cube .bottom { background: url(http://www.poolboy.fr/images/bottom.jpg) ; transform: rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 511px ) rotateY(   180deg ); }

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(511px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateZ(511px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
#cube { 
  /* transition: transform 1s; */
  transform: translateZ(512px) rotateY(10deg);
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that image are correctly displayed in Firefox ?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't use `transform-style`, it uses `-moz-transform-style`.  Try to replace that in your CSS code.  Make sure `transform-style: preserve-3d;` becomes `-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;`

**[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions)** is a list of Firefox extensions for CSS, use it well.

From Comment:

I took a deeper look at this, and found no issues with Hardware acceleration and that the `-moz-` prefix doesn't do anything, really. However, I did find that increasing the `perspective` did have an impact (A quite massive one on my part) on how the cube rendered. For my display (1920 x 1080), the sweet-spot of not losing quality and making it actually work was to set `perspective: 1000px;` to `perspective: 1250px;` I hope this helps, cause it certainly fixed it for me.

Comment: No difference prefixing this property with -moz-, here is the example : http://codepen.io/poolboy/full/RWXRZm/. In your link, `transform-style` is under 'Previously prefixed properties now standard'

Comment: @simonLeClerc
I took a deeper look at this, and found no issues with Hardware acceleration and that the `-moz-` prefix doesn't do anything really.  However, I did find that increasing the perspective _did_ have an impact (A quite massive one on my part) on how the cube rendered.  For my display (1920 x 1080), the sweet-spot of not losing quality and making it actually work was to set `perspective: 1000px;` to `perspective: 1250px;`

I hope this helps, cause it certainly fixed it for me on Firefox!